# Apex - i need Json format output

Tags: apex

I need apex class get the JSON output for this string:

`<text><Table><firstname>Text</firstname><lastname>One</lastname></table></text>`

I tried the following code:

```
public class Country1
{    
   public string jsonlist {get; set;}

   public void getExportjson()
   {

      http h=new http();
      HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
      string soapMsg ='<text><Table><firstname>Text</firstname><lastname>One</lastname></table></text>';
      req.setEndpoint(soapMsg);
      req.setMethod('GET');
      req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'Application/JSON; charset=utf-8');
      system.debug('Request&&&&:'+req);
      req.setCompressed(true); 

      httpresponse res=h.send(Req);
      system.debug('Json data&&&&:'+res.getbody());
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? You're setting an XML string as the end point for a request, the end point is supposed to be the URL of the service you're communicating with.

Comment: You want JSON for XML?

Comment: Yes, I need get json output for xml string

Answer (score 0):

From What I have understood, You want Json for the inputted XML.
The JSON would look something like.

```
    {

   "Table": [{

      "firstname": "Text",

      "lastname": "One"

   }]

}
```

Assuming this is the Required JSOn, you can get the Wrapper class as

```
    public class TableWrapper{
    public TableClass[] Table;
    class TableClass {
        public String firstname;    //Text
        public String lastname; //One
    }
    public static TableWrapper parse(String json){
        return (TableWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, TableWrapper.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi susanoo, i need to parse the xml string to apex class then get the output for json format.

Comment: HI, i need This is Possible  or not. Once we are parse the xml string to apex class and get the json format output, this is possible say me example apex class

Comment: ofc it is possible..You need to do XML parsing and store values in wrapper

Comment: yes, I did parse this XML string '<NewDataSet> <Table> <Country>British Indian Ocean Territory</Country> <City>Diego Garcia</City> </Table></NewDataSet>' in this apex class,but i don't know for how to run and get the json format output...

Comment: public class ConverXMLdata {
public retrievexmldata getxmldata(DOM.Document response) {
 retrievexmldata result = new retrievexmldata();
result.table = new List<Table>();DOM.XmlNode root = response.getRootElement();parseResponse4Summery(root, result);
return result;}    public static void parseResponse4Summery(DOM.XmlNode node, retrievexmldata res){

Comment: if (node.getNodeType() == DOM.XmlNodeType.ELEMENT) {if (node.getName() == 'NewDataSet') res.NewDataSet = node.getText();if (node.getName() == 'Results') {
Table sSummery = new Table();for (DOM.XmlNode ch: node.getChildren()) {
if (ch.getName() == 'Country') sSummery.Country= ch.getText();
if (ch.getName() == 'City') sSummery.City= ch.getText();}}}}

Comment: public class retrievexmldata{String NewDataSet {get;set;}
List<Table> Table{get;set;}public retrievexmldata() {} 
public retrievexmldata(String NewDataSet, List<table> Table){
this.NewDataSet = NewDataSet;this.Table= Table;}} public class table{

Comment: public String Country{get;set;}public String City{get;set;}public table(){}public table(String Country,String City){this.Country = Country;
this.City= City;}}}